# Why do we need to fund our smart contracts?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am new to all these blockchain technologies. One thing the instructor said and he did not explain it fully. Why do we need to fund our smart contracts? I mean we pay gas fees straight from our wallets right so why do we need to fund our smart contracts?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the contract does. Normally you don't need to fund it but this can vary from case to case.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, your contract would need to hold funds in case it needed to send transactions on your behalf.  Most contracts are built so that the end user is the one who pays the fees typically from their wallet of choice. If you go this route, then there is no need to fund your smart contract.

On the other hand if you want the contract to be the entity to make transfers on the users behalf, then the contract must use gas which it will need to get from somewhere.  Hence why you would need to fund your contract (in this case).